# Raspberry pi 4 gets hot while installing raspbian

Tags: raspbian, temperature, pi-4

I just got Raspberry pi 4 and it too hot while installing raspbian OS.

```
> vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=78.0'C
```

Is this normal ?  I installed NOOBS Lite from Windows 10 and installed in SD card. It's taking a time to install in Raspberry pi 4 since it's around 2 GB.

Comment: Welcome -- but what does "too hot" mean?  Have you measured the temperature?

Comment: Temp show 78. I ran below command./opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp

Comment: The context here is still not very clear; you initially wrote "while installing raspbian".  If that's the case and it has been busy for 15 minutes, 78 ℃ might be reasonable.  However, after it's been idling it should drop to < 50°.  You need to have a look at what it's doing, e.g., with `top`, which will show the CPU usage.

Comment: Even in  idle condition temp is 70-80 °C I ran top I don't  see CPU usage more than 5%.Also I see half red thermometer at right corner.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is normal.  Even when RPi 4 is idle, it is still very hot. When doing even simple tasks it gets hot, you can't even touch it.

The RPi 4 definitely needs active cooling.
https://youtu.be/AVfvhEJ9XD0
He shows the best way to cool the RPi4.

Comment: If the video is relevant, you should describe what's in it. Otherwise, remove the link.

Comment: I just did. Is this better?

Comment: Yes, at least now I have an idea what the video is about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 78°C is average (with CPU usage hovering around the 25% mark) with a single copper finned heat sink on CPU (nothing for the other ICs) for the RPi4 4GB inside the official case. Leaving the cover open reduces the temperature by a few degrees.

I've used a *micro-fan* to lower the temperature to 64°C at similar CPU usage rates.

FWIW, an idle RPi3 B+ (headless mode) hovers between 46-49°C in my farm.

This topic is slightly contentious because some folks (**not me!**) understand the reasons rather well and also have above average knowledge on tweaking heat transfer coefficients for conduction and convection.

Answer (score 0):

> Even in idle condition temp is 70-80 °C I ran top I don't see CPU usage more than 5%.Also I see half red thermometer at right corner.

The thermometer is an overheat warning, and I believe it also indicates the CPU is being throttled, which shouldn't happen until the temp > 80°C.  Throttling the CPU if it is idling probably doesn't do much good, and no, this is not the way it should be.

You should contact the distributor, this should qualify as a warranty issue.